# creating a custom organization chart layout using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a custom organization chart layout using HTML and CSS, but I'm facing some difficulties in achieving the desired layout. I've provided my current code below, along with a brief explanation of the layout I'm aiming for.

Here's the current code I'm using:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree ul ul ul::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; left: 50%; bottom: -20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 20px;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

.tree ul ul ul ul li a {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl !important; /* Vertical orientation */
    text-orientation: mixed !important;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text from wrapping */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Desired Layout:
I want to create an organization chart where the parent node is connected to a child node. The child node should have three grandchild nodes, which are connected horizontally to each other. The middle grandchild node should be connected vertically to the child node. I've attached an image of the desired layout[image][image].

Challenge:
I've tried modifying my existing code to achieve this layout, but I'm struggling with properly connecting the grandchild nodes horizontally and vertically as described.

Question:
Could someone please guide me on how to modify the code to achieve the desired organization chart layout? Specifically, how can I connect the three grandchild nodes horizontally while ensuring the middle grandchild is connected vertically to the child node?

I appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose/expectation of the CSS file and three JS files that aren't even being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer that adds responsivity so that both versions of the chart are possible:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

.tree ul ul ul ul li a {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    text-orientation: mixed !important;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text from wrapping */
    
    writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* Vertical orientation */
}



.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tree ul ul ul::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; left: 50%; bottom: -20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 20px;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
  right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .tree ul ul ul ul li a {
        writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    }

    .tree ul ul ul {
        padding-top : 0;
    }

    .tree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
        padding: 0 0 0 20px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        clear: left;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
    }
    .tree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li::before {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .tree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:last-child::before {
        height: 50%;
    }

    .tree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    }


    .tree ul ul ul li::before {
        width: 20px;
        left: 0;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc !important;
        border-top: none;
    }
    .tree ul ul ul li:last-child::before {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-right: none;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
    }
    .tree ul ul ul li::after {
        width: 20px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    }

    .tree ul ul ul ul {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    }

    .tree ul ul ul ul::before {
        border-left: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 20px;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
    }

    .tree ul ul ul ul li {
        float: none;
        padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
    }

    .tree ul ul ul ul li:first-child::before,
    .tree ul ul ul li:last-child::after {
        border: 0 none !important;
    }
    .tree ul ul ul ul li:first-child::after{
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 0 !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0 !important;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0 !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

.tree ul ul ul ul li a {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    /*writing-mode: vertical-rl !important;*/ /* Vertical orientation */
    text-orientation: mixed !important;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text from wrapping */
}



.tree ul ul ul {
    padding-top : 0;
}

.tree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
.tree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li::before {
    height: 100%;
}
.tree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:last-child::before {
    height: 50%;
}

.tree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}


.tree ul ul ul li::before {
    width: 20px;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.tree ul ul ul li:last-child::before {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.tree ul ul ul li::after {
    width: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree ul ul ul ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.tree ul ul ul ul::before {
    border-left: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}

.tree ul ul ul ul li {
    float: none;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
}

.tree ul ul ul ul li:first-child::before,
.tree ul ul ul li:last-child::after {
    border: 0 none;
}
.tree ul ul ul ul li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm working on creating an organization chart that needs to be responsive for both horizontal and vertical views. above design is correct for the vertical view (smaller screens) based on my requirements. However, I'm having trouble adjusting the layout to work properly in the horizontal view (larger screens).